# how to run docker commands inside AKS based vsts agents?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We were able to successfully add the deployment to Azuredevops Agent pool and could execute the pipeline on them by following the [Microsoft docs][1].

I used below docker file to install the software inside the container.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# To make it easier for build and release pipelines to run apt-get,
# configure apt to not require confirmation (assume the -y argument by default)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    jq \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    libcurl4 \
    libicu60 \
    libunwind8 \
    netcat \
    libssl1.0 \
    maven \
    python \
    python3 \
    docker \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./vstsagent/ .
COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

But Now I am confused with below points

- How to set Maven and java home directories along with Mavens custom setting.xml and node and gradle custom properties files in side this AKS based agents?
- Even though I put Docker software to install within the conatiner, it seems docker is not getting installed. So how we can run docker related tasks in our pipelines like "build image" nad push Image tasks within this aks based build agents?

Comment: Hi Vowneee, you could refer to this post for [deploy Docker images to Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS)](https://purple.telstra.com.au/blog/how-to-deploy-docker-images-to-azure-kubernetes-services-aks), and put the commands in a script for Azure Cli task